# Reduce audio playback latency from microphone input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, stream, web-audio-api, playback

I need to capture some input from microphone in javascript (from a browser) and playback audio in real time. But the latency I get is really ugly (about 200ms).

How can I reduce this ? Is javascript a good option to expect latency like 20 ms ?

I simply tried to capture the audio using `getUserMedia()` and `AudioContext` utils from `Web Audio API` and play it :

```
const constraints = {
  video: false,
  audio: {
    echoCancellation: false,
    noiseSuppression: false,
    autoGainControl: false
  }
}

var context = new AudioContext({
  latencyHint: 'interactive',
  sampleRate: 44100,
});

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then((stream) => {
    var source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    source.connect(context.destination);
  });
```

Any suggestion is welcome to minimize latency. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will help, but you should definitely turn off echo cancellation and other input processing if you're sending the audio to WebAudio.  See [echoCancellation constraint](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#def-constraint-echoCancellation) for details.  You probably also want to turn off gain control and noise suppression.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I didn't know about those constraints. Unfortunately, the latency is still really bad (a bit lower but still unacceptable).
I updated my code in my question.

Comment: One last thing to try is to try `new AudioContext({latencyHint: 0})` to get the context to use a lower latency.  If that doesn't help enough, then you should probably file a bug with your browser.  Having a real use-case will help them figure out how to make it better, if possible.

Comment: Maybe you can reduce the latency by not setting the sampleRate to 44100Hz. If the sampleRate of your audio output device is not 44100Hz then setting the sampleRate of the AudioContext to this value will cause the browser to do resampling which in turn adds some latency.